# assign users privileges PHP

Tags: php

I have a table that shows every all the users including the `admin` and the `seo`, I want to restrict the privileges to the users only see other users ( And not see the admin nor seo). Here's list of users:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [rid] => admin
            [first_name] => Admin
            [last_name] => Admin
            [email] => admin@admin.com
            [password] => b2be38504e4c8dedffab96534ff3df93
            [date_register] => 2014-02-18 08:27:28
            [last_connexion] => 2014-03-11 18:18:54
            [enable] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
            [rid] => seo
            [first_name] => SEO
            [last_name] => SEO
            [email] => seo@SEO.com
            [password] => 74709b45674cab2d2e9928578237a3c4
            [date_register] => 2014-02-18 08:27:28
            [last_connexion] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [enable] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 3
        [rid] => user
        [first_name] => Test    
        [last_name] => Test
        [email] => test@yahoo.com
        [password] => 2b2809a2b67df0e17d44de3b0d33e880
        [date_register] => 2014-02-18 08:27:51
        [last_connexion] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [enable] => 1
    )
```

And here's my code :

```
foreach ($users as $key => $value){
if (user('rid') != 'seo' && user('rid') != 'admin') { 
    unset($users[$key]['seo']);
    unset($users[$key]['admin']);
}
}
```

Hope you understood what I mean. Is there a error in my code?

Thanks

Comment: If this is coming from a db why don't you alter your select to only get users in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You need to use `==`  instead of `=` in your `if` condition

```
&& $value['email']== $email
```

instead of

```
&& $users[$key]['email']= $email
```

Comment: Sorry, but the issue here is that the user still sees the admin and the seo how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Can you post `user()` function here ?